# angular 2 app component not loading

Tags: javascript, angular

I am doing a simple angular 2 tutorial, but i just get 'loading' when trying to run my app. 
 this is my index.html file

```
 <html>
      <head>
        <title>Angular CV </title>
        <base href="/">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
        <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
         <!-- Polyfill for older browsers -->
        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <!-- 2. Configure SystemJS -->
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
          System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
        </script>
      </head>
      <!-- 3. Display the application -->
      <body>
        <my-app>Still Loading...</my-app>
      </body>
    </html>
```

app.component.ts

```
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      template: ''
    })
    export class AppComponent {

    }
```

full code here: https://github.com/trinajoy/angularcv

Comment: Is there an error in the console?

Comment: you should do npm install reflect-metadata and npm install reflect-portfinder.

Comment: in chrome developer tools i get the following errors

shim.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <  
(for line of code before <html>)

and for index.html
localhost/:18 Uncaught ReferenceError: System is not defined(…)

  System.import('app').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); }); 

and 
directive_normalizer.js:92 Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:(…)
- but im not sure which part of the code its referring to...

Comment: From your github repo, i think you are missing `systemjs.config.js`

Comment: ok, i just added systemjs.config.js to the project, but the app still doesnt load properly. It just reads loading, from my index.html file...

Answer (score 0):

[Angular-cli](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli) changed their system from SystemJS to Webpack since `beta.14`. It seems you're still using SystemJS, though.

You can migrate to Webpack following [these instructions](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/Upgrading-from-Beta.10-to-Beta.14). However, as you're just following a tutorial, I'd recommend to [install angular-cli from scratch](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation).

Comment: well i did the following npm uninstall -g angular-cli, npm cache clean, npm install -g angular-cli@latest, and started again, but from what i see, i have the same info in my json file and also the angular-cli json, i still get to the same point, where my app just displays 'loading' from index file..

full code here: https://github.com/trinajoy/angulartest.git

i have the same problem with a number of tutorials im trying

Comment: But you're still trying to import `SystemJS` in your `index.html` (lines 17-19) (and also trying to load SystemJS scripts).

Comment: so im donig  - npm uninstall -g angular-cli, npm cache clean, npm install -g angular-cli@latest - and still not getting the beta 14..? am i not doing it right?

Comment: actually i think changed the index.html to match the tutorial i was doing.. i guess thats where the problem was..